# Android: get data from internet via URL.getContent() - no need for HttpUrlConnection?

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

So far I've learned if I need to implement a method to retrieve data from an Internet server in an Android app, it's good to use `HttpUrlConnection` from Java as follows:

```
URL url = "http:\\www.stackoverflow.com/questions/json";
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
     InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
     readStream(in);
   } finally {
     connection.disconnect();
   }
```

But [here on YouTube](https://youtu.be/fRHEp35NZzw?list=PLVTeA3WccG_7Kgey8VtmFLCEVR5jeZNFK) a man says not to retrieve a Bitmap simply by calling:

```
InputStream in = (InputStream) url.getContent();
```

I would like to point out that here we get Content from the url without calling `HttpURLConnection.class` and `openConnection()` method.

I followed that tutorial and the code compiles.

1. Am I missing something, or isn't it necessary to use `HttpURLConnection.class` and `openConnection()`?
2. If it's not necessary, why does Android documentation recommend using it?

Yes, I know, that besides `HttpURLConnection` it possible to use other packages (libraries), this question isn't about that. What I ask, is why I should use any type of connection if it's so simple to get data just calling `URL.getContent()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's not necessary to use HttpURLConnection.class and getConnection() method?

There is no `getConnection()` method. There is `openConnection()`. `getContent()` on an HTTP/HTTPS URL will use `openConnection()` as part of its processing, as is noted in [the documentation for `getContent()` on `URL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html#getContent()).

> why Android documentation recommend me to use it?

Nobody but the author of that documentation can tell you why they wrote that documentation. The author of that documentation is unlikely to respond to your question.

Personally, I would recommend against the use of `getContent()` for several reasons:

1. It is undocumented and not type-safe, meaning that the behavior could change on any device at the whim of the device manufacturer.
2. HTTP error handling, with respect to `getContent()`, is also undocumented. What happens when the server returns a 404? A 401? A 500? A 301? A 304? Some of those you will need explicit handling for (e.g., retry with exponential backoff), which means you need to get at the response code. At minimum, you need to know whether the request succeeded and therefore whether the whatever-the-object-is that you get from `getContent()` will be valid. Your approach does not seem to offer much for this.
3. Similarly, your approach ignores HTTP headers (request or response), such as those related to caching (`Last-Modified`, `ETag`, `Expires`).

Comment: Thank you very much, I understood! _URL getContent() This method is a shorthand for: openConnection().getContent()_ So, in both examples openConnectio() exists, so the difference is just giving this connection to HttpURLConnection class or dealing with it direct (not recommended)

Comment: May I ask about connect() method? Why some documentations mention it like `HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); connection.connect();` but there are plenty documentations, which don't mention this method to use

Comment: @Vick.GV: IIRC, `connect()` will be called lazily once you start trying to work with the output (e.g., call `getInputStream()`).

Answer (score 1):

Sure he used `HttpURLConnection`, but instead of `connection.getInputStream()` he used `connection.getContent()` which retruns an `Object` instance.

As of the documentation; `getContent()` already uses `getInputStream()` internally to retrieve the content and `getContentType()` to load the proper class (such as `JSON`).

I recommend you to use `getInputStream()` because it allows you to handle errors, different types of response codes and to decide which class to use with this data type.

also URL has a method called getContent() whitch is a shorthand for: connection.getContnet();